# CompositionTarget.Rendering event for Windows Form?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

This code is in WPF:

```
CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(Update);
CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(Draw);
```

I would like to translate do Windows Form. Can I do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalent is the Form.Paint event.  It isn't exactly a very good match, each control in Winforms gets its own event.  A fundamental difference between WPF and Winforms.  A child control may need to paint itself (compare Control.Invalidate) without the parent ever getting the event.

Comment: hmmm ok thank you.
May I check keyboard input inside a paint event?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?  Keyboard input is event driven.

Comment: similar as XNA do. It has one loop for "update" which we should control things like keyboard input.